# Add Column containing consecutive weekdays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe containing multiple accounts and dates. I want to add a column that counts the consecutive dates for each account, giving the total number of consecutive dates in that 'run' of consecutive dates.

eg. For account B we see there are two groups of consecutive dates (2nd,3rd) and (5th,6th) we assign 2 to each row.

**Ideally I would like to only exclude weekend dates aswell, so Friday --> Monday is counted as consecutive**

Input Dataframe

| Account | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/2023 |
| A | 01/02/2023 |
| A | 01/03/2023 |
| A | 01/05/2023 |
| B | 01/02/2023 |
| B | 01/03/2023 |
| B | 01/05/2023 |
| B | 01/06/2023 |
| C | 01/01/2023 |
| C | 01/02/2023 |
| C | 01/04/2023 |
| C | 01/05/2023 |
| D | 01/01/2023 |
| D | 01/05/2023 |
| D | 01/07/2023 |
| D | 01/08/2023 |
| D | 01/09/2023 |
| D | 01/10/2023 |

My output would ideally be

| Account | Date | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/2023 | 3 |
| A | 01/02/2023 | 3 |
| A | 01/03/2023 | 3 |
| A | 01/05/2023 | 1 |
| B | 01/02/2023 | 2 |
| B | 01/03/2023 | 2 |
| B | 01/05/2023 | 2 |
| B | 01/06/2023 | 2 |
| C | 01/01/2023 | 4 |
| C | 01/02/2023 | 4 |
| C | 01/03/2023 | 4 |
| C | 01/04/2023 | 4 |
| D | 01/01/2023 | 1 |
| D | 01/05/2023 | 1 |
| D | 01/07/2023 | 4 |
| D | 01/08/2023 | 4 |
| D | 01/09/2023 | 4 |
| D | 01/10/2023 | 4 |

Thanks,

Comment: All of your `C` accounts have the same date in the input frame but your expected output frame has different dates. Also, your sample does not include the situation you are looking for: "Friday --> Monday is counted as consecutive"

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your output, but to group and count successive business days, I would use:

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=False)

group = (df['Date'].ne(df['Date'].add(pd.offsets.BusinessDay()).shift())
          .groupby(df['Account']).cumsum()
        )

df['Length'] = df.groupby(['Account', group]).transform('size')
```

Output:

```
   Account       Date  Length
0        A 2023-01-01       3
1        A 2023-01-02       3
2        A 2023-01-03       3
3        A 2023-01-05       1
4        B 2023-01-02       2
5        B 2023-01-03       2
6        B 2023-01-05       2
7        B 2023-01-06       2
8        C 2023-01-01       4
9        C 2023-01-02       4
10       C 2023-01-03       4
11       C 2023-01-04       4
12       D 2023-01-01       1
13       D 2023-01-05       1
14       D 2023-01-07       1
15       D 2023-01-08       3
16       D 2023-01-09       3
17       D 2023-01-10       3
```

Answer (score 0):

I exclude the weekends from the sorted data set. Next, group by Account and shift to see the elapsed days.  Lastly, create a running total column.

```
data="""Account Date
A   01/01/2023
A   01/02/2023
A   01/03/2023
A   01/05/2023
B   01/02/2023
B   01/03/2023
B   01/05/2023
B   01/06/2023
C   01/01/2023
C   01/02/2023
C   01/04/2023
C   01/05/2023
D   01/01/2023
D   01/05/2023
D   01/07/2023
D   01/08/2023
D   01/09/2023
D   01/10/2023"""

def exclude_weekends(df):
    """
    Excludes weekends
    """
    df['weekday'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday
    df = df[df['weekday'] < 5]
    return df

df= pd.read_csv(StringIO(data.strip()), sep='\s+', parse_dates=["Date"], engine='python')
# sort by account and date
df = df.sort_values(['Account', 'Date'])
df = exclude_weekends(df)
# create a new column that counts the consecutive dates
df['consecutive_dates'] = df.groupby('Account')['Date'].transform(lambda x: (x - x.shift()).dt.days)
# replace the NaT values with 1
df['consecutive_dates'] = df['consecutive_dates'].fillna(1)
df['running_total'] = df.groupby('Account')['consecutive_dates'].cumsum()
print(df.head(100))
```